# vimwiki vs viki vs vim outliner etc

Tags: vim, productivity

I've only tried vimwiki and TVO, but I'm interested to know the feature comparison.
My daily logs are typically short (< 10 lines) and they're saved in different files with vimwiki, which is kinda inconvenient to me.

Comment: Did you consider? VOom (http://vim-voom.webs.com/) Can't live without this plugin anymore.

Comment: @vtest: Hey that's a neat one. I just need to press 'enter' to go back to the class browser outline in python (which is more simpler than taglist). thanks